# Error: Package requirements (libprotobuf-c >= 1.0.1) were not met

Tags: linux, protocol-buffers, embedded-linux, autoconf, pkg-config

I am using [protobuf-c](https://github.com/protobuf-c/protobuf-c) from GitHub. When I run make this error occurs.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/protobuf-c/protobuf-c.git
Cloning into 'protobuf-c'...
$ cd protobuf-c
$ ./autogen.sh
...
```

And then:

```
$ ./configure
...

checking whether g++ supports C++11 features with -std=c++11... yes
checking for protobuf... no
checking for protobuf... no
configure: error: Package requirements (libprotobuf-c >= 1.0.1) were not met:
No package 'libprotobuf-c' found

Consider adjusting the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables `libprotobuf_c_CFLAGS`
and `libprotobuf_c_LIBS` to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
make: *** [config.status] Erreur 1
```

What is the problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: Do you mean that you get that error when you try to configure protobuf-c itself, or when you try to configure some other project that uses protobuf-c?

Comment: i get it when i try to compile protobuf-c itself

Comment: Well, the error messages you present seem to indicate that the problem is that the very package you say you are trying to build is not already present.  It could be that protobuf-c has a very broken build system producing such an issue, but I don't see anything in the Autoconf sources that seems to support that proposition.  Please, then, present a step-by-step procedure by which the issue can be reproduced.

Answer (score 7):

> How can i fix this configure error about libprotobuf-c?
>   configure: error: Package requirements (libprotobuf-c >= 1.0.1) were not met...

Ensure you have these prerequisites installed. The `README.md` does not list them.

The packages for Ubuntu are:

- libprotobuf-dev
- libprotoc-dev
- protobuf-compiler

The packages for Fedora are:

- protobuf-devel
- protobuf-compiler

If you are missing `libprotobuf-dev`, then you get the error:

> ```
> configure: error: Package requirements (protobuf >= 2.6.0) were not met...
> ```

If you are missing `libprotoc-dev`, then you get the error:

> ```
> checking for google/protobuf/compiler/command_line_interface.h:
> configure: error: required protobuf header file not found
> ```

If you are missing `protobuf-compiler`, then you get the error:

> ```
> configure: error: Please install the protobuf compiler from
> https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/
> ```

---

With the prereqs installed you should successfully configure with a summary like:

```
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating protobuf-c/libprotobuf-c.pc
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands

protobuf-c 1.3.1

    CC:                     gcc
    CFLAGS:                 -g -O2
    CXX:                    g++ -std=c++11
    CXXFLAGS:               -g -O2
    LDFLAGS:
    LIBS:

    prefix:                 /usr/local
    sysconfdir:             ${prefix}/etc
    libdir:                 ${exec_prefix}/lib
    includedir:             ${prefix}/include
    pkgconfigdir:           ${libdir}/pkgconfig

    bigendian:              no
    protobuf version:       libprotoc 3.0.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer !! i installed libprotobuf-dev
and libprotoc-dev but i coud not install  protobuf-compiler i don't know why it says " impossible to find packet " when i run sudo apt-get install protobuf-compiler , also the  libprotobuf-c error is always there i tried to export pkgconfig path but it's useless , other than that you mentioned  , what can be the reason ? ps: i am using ubuntu 14.04 thank you .

Comment: `apt-cache search protobuf`.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem when I build protobuf-c-rpc. I figure out the protobuf-c installs the libprotobuf-c.pc by default to **/usr/local/lib** rather than **/usr/lib64**.

Maybe you can use `./configure --libdir=/usr/lib64`, or just copy the libprotobuf-c.pc from **/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig** to the right place (like **/usr/lib64/pkgconfig**).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).